# Cached images are not displayed in my ListView- React Native

Tags: react-native

i'm new in smartphones app developer, so i have this trouble, I'm trying to optimize my application by trying to store the cache images, however, by performing the save action on the device these are not shown, but it shows me in the debug that if they are stored but I can not see them, they are invisible...

Without Cache

[image]

Cache stored

[image]

Comment: is this react native question? if so where you are storing data?

Comment: you may want to add mime type while reading data from cache if its stored as binary file.

Answer (score 0):

With react-native you can't do this because when you `require` an image from a path, this path has to be a fixed string. You cannot do, for example:

```
const myImage = require(`/cache/${imageId}.png`);
```

Anyway, network images are already cached AFAIK.